# How can I create a summary report using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with a primary key and row key column. The data looks like below. The data has already been loaded into a table that is a collection.

```
Primary Key    Row Key
01000100001  000001 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=1, Chapter ID=1 and Page ID=1
01000100001  000002 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=1, Chapter ID=1 and Page ID=2
01000100001  000003 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=1, Chapter ID=1 and Page ID=3
01000100002  000004 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=1, Chapter ID=2 and Page ID=4
01000100002  000005 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=1, Chapter ID=2 and Page ID=5
01000100002  000006 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=1, Chapter ID=2 and Page ID=6
01000200003  000007 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=2, Chapter ID=3 and Page ID=7
01000200003  000008 - Subject ID=1, Book ID=2, Chapter ID=3 and Page ID=8
02000300004  000009 - Subject ID=2, Book ID=3, Chapter ID=4 and Page ID=9
02000300005  000010 - Subject ID=2, Book ID=3, Chapter ID=5 and Page ID=10
```

The collection class is called Pages and contains a column called PrimaryKey which is made up of the following:

```
2 column Subject ID
4 column Book ID
4 column Chapter ID
```

I need to create a report that looks something like the following and I am wondering
if and how I could create a query for this with LINQ.

```
Subject  Books  Chapters      Pages

01         2         3           8
02         1         2           2
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the group by and sum features the linq query would look something like this:

```
from page in pages
group page by new { 
                    page.subjectId
                    , page.bookId
                    , page.chapterId 
                 } into group
select new {
             group.key.SubjectId
             , group.key.bookId
             , group.Key.chapterId
             , total = pages.sum(s => s.Page)
}
```

Sorry that I don't have visual studio available right now, but this should give you a pretty good start.

Answer (score 0):

If the report is getting more complex, just create a view in SQL server and read the view with LINQ - it's much easier!

Comment: I'm using Windows Azure Table storage. Not relational :-(